# Populate a date field based on text fields being updated

Tags: date, auto-populate, single-line-of-text

I am supporting a team with the SharePoint site that is used to request tasks to be completed.

When the "Item ID"(Single Line of text) field is populated we want the "Date Item ID Generated"(Date type) field to be automatically populated.

The same thing would also be done for the Item reviewed fields. We are using this for various metrics so it is important for these dates to be accurate.

[image]

I have done quite a bit of research around this but, I can't find what we are looking for as everything that I have read is that the date field would be updated after the item is opened and saved again, which we don't want that to happen.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in many ways as mentioned below:

1. **Calculated Column:**
    Create 2 calculated columns, one for each date field you want to save. You can look for calculated date formulae [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14)). Based on your text field, you can make your formula add the date to your calculated date field.

**Note**: Calculated columns will not take people & group, lookup, ID etc. fields in its formula, [Source](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/09/11/supported-fields-in-calculated-column-sharepoint/).

2. **Designer Workflow:**
   Create & Run a workflow on item created and changed conditions which will check for your text fields and based on that will update the date fields.
3. **Javascript:**
   One more way to achieve this is using javascript on the new and edit forms. Add your logic to javascript code and add it in content editor/script editor web part on new form and edit form.

Best way would be to use calculated columns.